# Paginación de la API de Instagram con React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Tengo un inconveniente al hacer el paginado de la API de instagram.

El problema es que al llegar a la tercera o cuarta página el renderizado empieza a fallar y devuelve páginas anteriores y en un momento ya se vuelve loco y tarda mucho en renderizar.

El paginado lo hago cambiando el estado cuando se hace click en los botones, y paso la url que me envía la paging.

Dejo el código abajo:

```
function Peticion () {

let FeedInstagram = `https://graph.instagram.com/me/media? 
   fields=thumbnail_url,media_url,children,
   children_url,timestamp,media_type,caption,permalink&limit= 
   10&access_token=${token}`

const [url, setUrl] = useState(FeedInstagram);
const [post, setPost] = useState([]);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
        const Post = async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            let res = await axios.get(url),
                data = await res.data,
                pagina = await data.paging,
                json = await data.data,
                next = pagina.next,
                prev = pagina.previous;
            setPost(json);
            setLoading(false)
            window.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
                (prev===undefined
                    ?anterior.current.classList.add('inactive')
                    :(anterior.current.classList.remove('inactive'),
                    e.target.matches('.previous')&&setUrl(prev)))
                (next===undefined
                    ?siguiente.current.classList.add('inactive')
                    :(siguiente.current.classList.remove('inactive'),
                    e.target.matches('.next')&&setUrl(next)))
            })
            }
            Post()
        }, [url]);
return (
    <>
        <div>
            <Data post={post} loading={loading} />
        </div>
        <div className='butons'>
            <button className='previous botones'>Anterior</button>
            <button className='next botones'>Siguiente</button>
        </div>
    </>
  )
 }    

export default Peticion;
```

Comment: Por qué en el useEffect usas `window.addEventListener` en vez de usar un `onClick` directamente en los botones? Recuerda que cada vez que presiones los botones `Anterior` y `Siguiente` estarás agregando un `EventListenter`, esto hace que la aplicación sea cada vez más lenta si sucede muchas veces.

Comment: si entiendo, pero no puedo usar la funcion que esta dentro del useefect , o de que manera puedo usarla? porque ahi esta la complicacion, si creo la funcion fuera del Uef no puedo usar las variables del axios, y si lo hago dentro no puedo usarla en los botones, hay alguna forma?

Comment: Pero para eso existe el hook de estado, useState(), para mantener un estado interno en el componente. Simplemente crea un estado de la página por ejemplo `const [pagina, setPagina] = useState(null)` y ya puedes usarlo fuera del useEffect. Dentro del useEffect solo seteas el estado cuando obtienes la respuesta de la API: `setPagina(pagina)`

Comment: Me quedo funcionando muchas gracias!

Comment: Si esto solucionó tu problema, te recomiendo que respondas tu propia pregunta (se puede y es muy normal) para que los demas puedan encontrar la solución a un problema similar. De paso ganarás puntos si la votan positivamente ;)
Si quieres puedo contestarla para que quede bien en claro. Pero te recomiendo que lo hagas tu con la solución exacta a tu problema

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente crea un estado de la página por ejemplo const [pagina, setPagina] = useState(null) y ya puedes usarlo fuera del useEffect. Dentro del useEffect solo seteas el estado cuando obtienes la respuesta de la API: setPagina(pagina)

gracias Andres Gardiol, esta fue la solucion a mi problema